# Makefile special symbols in variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to redirect command output either to log file, or to screen and log file depending on `VERBOSE` environment variable. Log file name depends on the target.

I am trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
ifeq "$(VERBOSE)" "yes"
    OUTPUT := 2>&1 | tee $$@.log
else
    OUTPUT := 1>$$@.log 2>&1
endif

target:
        my_command $(OUTPUT)
```

But I end up with `.log` file instead of `target.log`.

I.e., when rule is executed, say for `$ make VERBOSE=yes target`, make sees the rule as

```
target:
        my_command 2>&1 | tee .log
```

instead of

```
target:
        my_command 2>&1 | tee $@.log
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `:=` if you want the variable to have references to other variables that are not set yet: `:=` expands the value of the variable immediately when the variable is assigned.  Once the variable is expanded the first time, it won't be re-expanded later.  `$@` is not set until the variable is used in the rule.  Change to use `=` instead and remove the escape:

```
ifeq "$(VERBOSE)" "yes"
    OUTPUT = 2>&1 | tee $@.log
else
    OUTPUT = 1>$@.log 2>&1
endif
```

and it will work.